# Does the request module also use wsgi?

Tags: python

I understood that wsgi changes web requests like http to code that Python can understand. So we put the wsgi application between a web server like nginx and a web framework like django. That way, django can understand the web request. However, I was confused because I remembered the requests module. This requests module also eventually performs http communication. I can send various requests such as get, post, etc. and receive responses. Then is the request module also using wsgi?

Comment: No. One is a server component and the other is a client.